# Error libreria faltante visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo una solución en VS 2013 a la cual por error le agregue unos paquetes nuget, desinstale los paquetes por la consola pero ahora en la maquina de produccion al ejecutar la aplicación me sale el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

En el proyecto no hago referencia a esa libreria ni es necesaria para la aplicacion, yo creo que en algun archivo del proyecto esta haciendo referencia a esta libreria pero por mas que he buscado no encuentro donde la referencia, ¿alguien ha tenido un problema similar?

Comment: si revisas la carpeta de compilacion \bin\Debug puede ver la dll de esta libreria? Tambien revisa si algun otro proyecto no la quedo referenciando, o quizas alguna otra libreria la necesita como dependencia. El mensaje indica que esta buscando es libreria pero no la encuentra. Lo que no se es como hiciste para que llegara aproduccion, se supone que primero se prueban las cosas en un entorno local

Comment: No Leandro, en la carpeta debug no esta la libreria, la aplicacion compila sin errores ni warnings y obviamente esa libreria no esta en las referencias

Comment: Compila sin errores o warning porque es un problema que se da en runtime cuando ejecuta.  que version del framework net usas?  validaste sino hay alguna otra libreria externa que referencies por nuget, que pudiera tenerla por dependencia?

Comment: Version 4.5.2, en este momento no se referencia ninguna libreria por Nuget